# Combining mismatched data with specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he6SS.png)

I am trying to turn ABCD into HIJK. from another forum i understand now `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")` will find unique values, and i just apply this to both lists to find unique ones in both. But my problem now is the instance of "eric," which appears twice, and how to make this grab the correct $ amount (pay for eric 1 coming from 1 and pay for eric 2 coming from 2)

Comment: You provide just a table of stuff, with no explanation of what we're looking at or how the columns relate.  It isn't obvious what the data represents or what the problem is.

Comment: I have companies (here “1”, “2”) with people who work at the companies underneath and their payrolls, which are in a separate column. Next to the company number, I have the total payroll, and then how that payroll is split between the employees. I get this data about the companies from two different sources, which are pulling different information for the companies (different employees, payrolls etc) which I am trying to reconcile to see where there are difference.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please refrain from [asking the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1393174/align-two-columns-in-excel-based-on-1-criteria) multiple times.