# Reconciling differences when data repeats in a sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: Example data]

In the example data, say we have Company 1 and Company 2. Under each company is the state in which employees work, followed by the name of the employee(s) which work(s) in that state. In the column next to this, we have the payroll, by Company, state and employee(s), each.

This data is pulled from two different sources, which provide different payroll data. I am trying to reconcile these differences, to see exactly where payroll differences are. I've been guided to use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")`the problem with this formula is say if a name or state repeats, the payroll of the first instance of that name is pulled, instead of the payroll for the specific company that person works at. Here, this instance is "eric," which appears both under Company 1 and Company 2.

Is there any way to make this formula, or any formula, pull from the new instance of the name, or erase its "memory" of the first instance of the name or state to pull the new instance?

Comment: What have you tried? [Searching around](https://www.google.com/search?q=vlookup+return+nth+match) I found [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319636/find-second-vlookup-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining mismatched data with specific criteria](https://superuser.com/questions/1393174/align-two-columns-in-excel-based-on-1-criteria)